# Хранение кодов хаффмана

Tags: python, huffman

Как хранить коды в одном файле вместе с таблицей декодирования?

Comment: Это как рядом с банковской картой хранить листик с пин-кодом )

Comment: может sha256 воспользоваться ?

Comment: @vikttur этот алгоритм не шифрует, а сокращает количество бит для хранения информации, сжатие без потерь.

Comment: @Интик это не хранение паролей.

Comment: похоже мы перепутали Hellman и Huffman

Comment: А вам во время записи известны размеры таблицы или кодов ? Если да, то пишите скажем 4 или 8 байт длины, потом блок этой длины (например таблицу). А после него даже слитно можно писать следующий блок (коды). При чтении берете длину и точно знаете сколько читать в таблицу и все что осталось - коды